# Shortcut: Move an item to the top of the backlog

Tags: azure, azure-devops, backlog

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/navigation/keyboard-shortcuts?view=azure-devops#backlogs), I should be able to **move an item to the top of the backlog** via <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>. I am able to do it manually via drag-and-drop, but the shortcut doesn't seem to work. Do you guys have problems with the shortcuts or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to reproduce your issue, and I have submitted a feedback at link below, please follow the link for any update.:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/998185/keyboard-shortcuts-to-move-an-item-to-the-top-of-t.html

---

**Update from product team:**

> We have created a bug for the engineering team to address as time
>   permits. Because of the nature of the issue, it is going to be a lower
>   priority bug for us. But we hope to get it addressed in the next few
>   sprints.

Answer (score 0):

This only applies to the Boards:

> You can use the following keyboard shortcuts from any Kanban board, that is, when working from Boards>Boards or Work>Board page.

...so unfortunately it does not work in the Backlog, only in the Sprint Backlog.